# Pasar resultado ciclo For a un ARRAY unidimensional

Tags: java

Tengo un arreglo Bidimensional llamado "info", de "n" filas y "7" columnas. El cual lo recorro con el siguiente código:

Nota: Comienzo a recorrer el arreglo a partir de la columna "1";

```
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++){  
double a=0.0, b=0.0;  
for (int y=1; y < info[x].length; y++){  
double numEntero = Double.parseDouble(info[x][y]);  
a=(a+numEntero);  
b=(a/7);  
}  
System.out.println(b);  
}
```

Al finalizar el ciclo for me arroja esto:

```
9.857142857142858  
9.257142857142856  
7.914285714285713  
8.285714285714286  
8.085714285714285  
9.285714285714283  
9.057142857142859  
9.4  
10.0
```

Como podrán notar, el arreglo original es String, (el cual contiene números) y convierto a double los datos almacenados en él. Sumo las columnas de la "1" a la "7" (ya que omito la columna 0) y las divido entre "7". AL final las almaceno en una variable double llamada "b".

¿Hay alguna forma pasar la variable "b" a un nuevo arreglo unidimensional?, es decir, pasar este resultado  a un nuevo Array. ¿Se podrá?

```
9.857142857142858  
9.257142857142856  
7.914285714285713  
8.285714285714286  
8.085714285714285  
9.285714285714283  
9.057142857142859  
9.4  
10.0
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaras el array antes del ciclo y lo rellenas en cada recorrido del bucle.

```
double[] miArray = new double[info.length]; int c=0;
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++){  
  double a=0.0, b=0.0;  
  for (int y=1; y < info[x].length; y++){  
   double numEntero = Double.parseDouble(info[x][y]);  
   a=(a+numEntero);  
   b=(a/7);  
   miArray[c] = b; c = c+1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Me parece tienes mal escrito el tipo de dato del arreglo miArray

Comment: Ya lo había corregido, el autocorrector, gracias

Comment: No asignas un valor a `miArray`, este código lanza un NullPointerException.

Comment: Ya está inicializado

Comment: Esto solo funcionará si la segunda dimensión tiene siempre tamaño `1`, de lo contrario `miArray` no tendrá tamaño suficiente. O se cuenta el número de elementos antes, o tienes que usar una estructura dinámica (`List` o similar).

Comment: Gracias Carmen por tu orientación !!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a todos por su orientación. Me ha sido realmente muy útil. Les comento que la solución que encontré gracias a su ayuda fue la siguiente:

double[] miArray = new double[info.length];
int c=0;
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++){
double a=0.0, b=0.0;
for (int y=1; y < info[x].length; y++){
double numEntero = Double.parseDouble(info[x][y]);
a=(a+numEntero);
b=(a/7);
miArray[c] = b;
}
c++;
}

Gracias Carmen, saludos !!!  :)